# Pasar el valor de una tabla a un textfield-Dialog react

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una tabla de usuarios que lleno por medio de un `useEffect` que trae los datos de una **API**, cada fila tiene un **boton** que abre un `Dialog` para agregar una suscripcion a la tabla `subscription`. Hay un dato que tienen en comun la tabla `Users` y la tabla `subscription` el campo `Code`, quisiera que cuando  abra el `Dialog` tome el valor del campo **`Code`** de la fila a la que le dio `click` y lo muestre en el `Dialog`.

As como se muestra en la imagen, si al hacer `click` en la fila con el `code 523` en el `Dialog` aparezca el valor `523`.

¿Alguna idea o sugerencia para poder lograrlo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
const initialState={code:0, email:'', alias:''}

const[subscription, setSubscription]=useState(initialState);

const handleChange=(event)=>{
    setSubscription({...subscription,[event.target.name]:event.target.value})
}

const handleSubmit=(event)=>{

    event.preventDefault();

    if(!subscription.code || !subscription.email || !subscription.alias) 
        return
            const postSubscription=async()=>{
                try {
                    axios.post('/api/Subscription/add',subscription);
                    props.history.push('/Subscription'); 
                }
                catch (error) {
                    console.log('error', error);
                }
            }
            postSubscription();
} 
            <MaterialTable
            title="Users"
            columns={[
                  { title: 'Code', field: 'code' , type: 'numeric'},
                  { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
                  { title: 'Lastname', field: 'lastname' },
                  { title: 'Age', field: 'age', type: 'numeric'},
            ]}
            data={user.Users}
            options={{     
              maxBodyHeight: '300px',
              headerStyle: { position: 'sticky', top: 0 } 
            }} 
         actions={[
                {
                  icon: 'account_box',
                  tooltip: 'Add subscription',
                  onClick:()=>{ handleClickOpen()}
                }
              ]}
          />
                  <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose} aria-labelledby="form-dialog-title">
                  <DialogTitle id="form-dialog-title">Subscription/DialogTitle>
                      <DialogContent>
                          <DialogContentText>
                              Subscription
                          </DialogContentText>
                              <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} 
                                  <TextField
                                      id="filled-name"
                                      name="code"
                                      label="Code"
                                      value={subscription.code}
                                      onChange={handleChange}
                                      margin="normal"
                                      variant="outlined"
                                  />
                                  <TextField
                                      id="filled-name"
                                      label="Email"
                                      value={subscription.email}
                                      name="email"
                                      onChange={handleChange}
                                      margin="normal"
                                      variant="outlined"
                                  />
                                  <TextField
                                      id="filled-multiline-static"
                                      label="Alias"
                                      value={subscription.alias}
                                      name="alias"
                                      onChange={handleChange}
                                      margin="normal"
                                      variant="outlined"
                                  />
                                  <Button
                                      variant="contained"
                                      color="primary"
                                      type="submit">
                                      Add
                                  </Button>
                              </form>
                      </DialogContent>
                  <DialogActions>
                    <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
                      Cancel
                    </Button>
                  </DialogActions>
                </Dialog>
              </div>
        );
        }
```

Comment: confirma que estas usando esta libreria https://github.com/mbrn/material-table y si la variable que tienes subscription esta en el estado o en las propiedades

Comment: @VictorAlvarez, si estoy utilizando esa libreria material-table, actualice  el codigo en la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el evento onClick que tienes en las actions puedes recibir el ***rowData*** tal como lo dice la documentación de la libreria y si lo que quieres es sacar el ***code*** de la fila lo puedes hacer actualizando el estado con ***setSubscription*** antes de abrir el Modal

```
actions={[
    {
        icon: 'account_box',
        tooltip: 'Add subscription',
        onClick:(event, rowData) => { 
            setSubscription({
                ...subscription,
                code : rowData.code
            })
            handleClickOpen()
        }
    }
]}
```

Comment: Tienes toda la razon en la documentacion viene lo del rowData y yo pensando que tenia que mandar los props en el Dialog o algo asi, gracias.

Comment: De nada amigo, recuerda la docutación es lo mas importante